# How can I use Electron, NW.js to "Serve" a React App that is accessible on a Local Network

Tags: node.js, reactjs, electron, desktop-application

I want to create an offline "Desktop Application/Website" with Electron. The UI/backend is essentially a "React Application".

> **What I'm trying to achieve:**

- Have a React application, which I run `npm start` would launch a server that can be accessed with a browser on my system (**and within the local network**)
- Create a downloadable cross platform "single file" (.app in dmg for Mac, .exe for Windows) that users can download, and run on their system (to achieve the above); for this I thought Electron would do
- The above file should work without the user being required to install dependencies locally (e.g. Node)

> **What I have done**

After creating the react app, and installing electron, I edited the electronjs entry file to become the below:

```
win.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: 'localhost:3000', //path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
    protocol: 'http:', //'file:',
    slashes: true
}))
```

Then, I used "concurrently" and "wait on" modules to ensure that when I run `npm start`, the react server starts first before electron launches. It works (for development)!

But when I package the app (for production, producing a Mac executable - MyProject.app), and run it, the server never starts, so electron shows a blank page for `localhost:3000`

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead -

```
win.loadURL("http://localhost:3000");
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, Ajey. The problem is not with the URL. The issue I have is that the React application itself does not start in production. So, there's really nothing running on "http://localhost:3000"

Comment: you are trying to start the server from electron? how?